# How a Mysql "LIKE" Function looks like?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I want to modify my search and thus want to create a function in MySQL. I have been using the "like" function till now. Is it possible to see the script/code for the "like" function in MySQL so that I could get the basic idea of how it works etc.?

I searched a lot on google but could not get the answer.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/ best of luck...

Answer (score 0):

The Like function searches for a particular column name, then returns matches similar to the LIKE search string given.
Here is a simple example:

```
$search_text='text';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE field_name LIKE '%search_text'%';
```

Comment: I suspect the OP knows this.

Comment: I think I've understood the user's exact question. He/she needs to understand the real work behind the LIKE function.

Comment: very true, i want to know how "like" function works. any suggestions would be helpful.